# How to preserve key when joining to a preference table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join

I have a table of customers, and a table of customer preferences, where:

```
create table customer (
  customerId number,
  name varchar2(200),
  primary key (customerId)
);

create table pref (
  preftype number,
  customerId number,
  prefval varchar2(200),
  primary key (preftype, customerId)
);
```

So basically the pref table records the customer's preference based on each preference type. customerId is unique for each preftype.

Theoretically the following join should not lose the key-preserved property, but I am getting "ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table." Anyway I can rewrite the query to maintain the key-preservedness?

```
select rowid, vi.* from (
  select c.customerId, c.name, p.prefval
  from customer c, (select * from pref where preftype = 1) p
  where c.customerId = p.customerId (+)
) vi;
```

---

Restrictions / requirements:

In our case a query engine is building that outer query (the one with rowid) around the inner query, so we don't have as much control.

We'd like to have a query that can be wrapped around with something like:

```
select rowid, v.*
from
    ( 
    -- query
    ) v ;
```

Comment: Why all this mess of a query? Why not a simp!e `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: I have tried `LEFT JOIN`. It also gives `ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table.` error.

Comment: "*We'd like to have a query that..*" - not possible if you don't have control over the inner query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name True. In this case though I know the resultant query should theoretically be key-preserved, but want to write my query in such a way that Oracle recognize the key-preservedness.

Comment: It has been a week now, so I am rewarding the correct answer to @Balazs Papp, who came up with select rowid in the inner select clause first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. It is not guaranteed (well, it is, with `preftype=1`, but that is in the subquery, and that is not good enough for the optimizer) that your query returns at most 1 row for each key value from the base table. You need a unique constraint on `customerid` to make this work:

```
select rowid, vi.* from (
  select c.customerId, c.name, p.prefval
  from customer c, (select * from pref where preftype = 1) p
  where c.customerId = p.customerId (+)
) vi;

ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a
key-preserved table

alter table pref add unique(customerid);

Table altered.

select rowid, vi.* from (
  select c.customerId, c.name, p.prefval
  from customer c, (select * from pref where preftype = 1) p
  where c.customerId = p.customerId (+)
) vi;

no rows selected
```

This however may not be feasible for you, as a customer can have multiple different `preftypes` with your original design.

This works without the unique constraint (but not the same result):

```
alter table pref drop unique(customerid);

Table altered.

select rowid, vi.* from (
  select c.customerId, c.name, p.prefval
  from customer c, pref p
  where c.customerId = p.customerId (+)
  and p.preftype = 1
  ) vi;

no rows selected
```

Or be more specific with the rowid:

```
select vi.* from (
  select c.rowid as c_rowid, c.customerId, c.name, p.prefval
  from customer c, (select * from pref where preftype = 1) p
  where c.customerId = p.customerId (+)
) vi;

no rows selected
```

Comment: I tried your last query, unfortunately p.preftype = 1 in your last query cancels out the outer join.

Comment: @John L Yeah, did not pay enough attention, added another version, though I do not know what you need the `rowid` for.

Comment: Yeah, I think getting rowid from the primary table should be a good solution in general case. In our case a query engine is building that outer query (the one with rowid) around the inner query, so we don't have as much control. Wish I can upvote you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the reason for having doubly nested subqueries when a simple `LEFT JOIN` can give the same result:

```
select c.customerid, c.name, p.prefval   
       -- , c.rowid                        -- this errs
from customer c
    left join pref p
    on  c.customerid = p.customerid
    and p.preftype = 1 ;
```

Now, when we add `c.rowid` in the `SELECT` list, Oracle parser/optimizer is not able to identify that every row of `customers` is going to be joined with - at maximum - 1 row from `pref`. So it throws an error.

We can convert the `LEFT JOIN` to a subquery though - and no error is thrown:

```
-- query 2 --
select c.customerid, c.name, 
       ( select p.prefval
         from pref p
         where c.customerid = p.customerid
           and p.preftype = 1 
       ) as prefval,
       c.rowid                               -- but works here
from customer c ;
```

or putting the `customers` in a derived table and then left join to pref:

```
-- query 3 --
select c.customerid, c.name, p.prefval, c.rowid                       
from 
    (select c.*, c.rowid from customer c) c
    left join pref p
    on  c.customerid = p.customerid
    and p.preftype = 1 ;
```

Tested at [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/KXWDS20052)

Comment: This will not work. I need to maintain the key-preserved property because we need to select rowid out of the whole query.

Comment: Did you try this exact query and what error did you get?

Comment: You notice in my question that there is another `select rowid ...` wrapping around everything. I already tried your query and it fails that requirement. The error is `ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table.`

Comment: See my edit about that. But curious, what do you want the rowids for?

Comment: By the way, I did notice the wrapping. That's why my answer starts with *"I see no reason for having **doubly nested** subqueries"*. There's no need for wrapping, as far as we can see.

Comment: Please see my answers to @Balazs Papp for all these questions

Comment: The last query from Balazs Papp seems to be a valid alternative, too, equivalent to my last 2 queries. What's the problem with either of those?

Comment: If *"my answers"* refer to the comment: *" In our case a query engine is building that outer query (the one with rowid) around the inner query, so we don't have as much control."*, that should be an **edit into the question** (and much better if it was from the beginning so we don't have to do all these discussions in comments.) It helps everyone to understand better and answer, if all the requirements are in the question. (just saying so you know for the next one). ORMs are PITA ;)

Comment: I edited the question for you. Please edit again if I missed anything.